# Calling Oracle Stored Procedure using Hibernate?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Am new to hibernate. Am trying to call a oracle stored procedure through Hibernate. Can I get some steps to follow to call a procedure through Hibernate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21934310/how-to-call-oracle-stored-procedure-using-hibernate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335939/how-to-call-oracle-function-or-procedure-using-hibernate-4-entitymanager-or-jp

Answer (score 1):

Starting from JPA 2.1 You can use `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery` annotation. This annotation can be specified on an entity or mapped superclass

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name="fooStoredProcedure", procedureName="someProcedureName")
```